# How to allow apps to open and perform actions as sudo?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, sudo, kde

I am running Debian 12 with KDE Plasma desktop 5.27 and my problem is that every time I open an app it won't allow me to do things as sudo or permissions are not set correctly.

For example, when I open Dolphin file manager I can read, write and modify files in my home folder but if I go down to the root folders I can't write or modify files. I have to open a terminal create a file in root by using the sudo command. I want to be able to use Dolphin to do these tasks though.

Another example is KDE partition manager. When I open it I can see all my devices but if I try to format my USB drive I don't really get the option to do anything. All options are greyed out and there is a lock next to the partition.

Is there anyway that I can just open apps as sudo and allow them to have sudo access so that I don't have to go to the terminal to complete these tasks?

Comment: It would be better to figure out what permissions these programs need that SUDO "fixes", and then assign those permissions to the applications. However, there ARE things that should be limited to SUDO only. Changing partitions is not a daily task, and so should remain as a SUDO-only process. I presume you mean the Dolphin emulator, and in general you should have your emulation files in locations you CAN access, which should be your home folder, or you should adjust permissions on whatever shared location you're trying to work from.

Comment: Your request breaks Linux's security model.  There is a reason that a standard user can't do the things you mention.  And @music2myear .. they mean the dolphin file manager.

Comment: I think you should not assume the true issue is the same simply because root "solves" all the issues. Approach each of your issues individually and solve that problem using the method appropriate to it. For THIS question, take a few steps back, choose one specific problem, do some work solving it, and bring only that question here.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas OP didn't specify. I did a quick web search and the emulator came up first. The base point remains, and we agree on that I think.

Comment: Some apps, like FeatherPad in Debian 12, only ask for root/authentication when trying to save (root) files. A "Saving as root. Waiting for Authentication..." message and an "Authenticate... needed to run /usr/bin/cp as the super user" password popup appear (I think using pkexec / polkit framework). And Thunar (file manager) can set an "Open root Thunar here", again using `pkexec thunar`

Comment: Thank you @music2myear, I just want to clarify that I am indeed talking about the Dolphin file manager. I should have been more specific and I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, when I open Dolphin I can read, write and modify files in my home folder but if I go down to the root folders I can't write or modify files. I have to open a terminal create a file in root by using the sudo command. I want to be able to use Dolphin to do these tasks though.

Use KIO's "access as admin" feature by opening `admin:/`. (This often comes as a separate `kio-admin` package; it should work across all "KDE native" apps. The same kind of functionality also exists in GNOME (GTK) apps, without any separate installation.)

> Another example is KDE partition manager. When I open it I can see all my devices but if I try to format my USB I don't really get the option to do anything. All options are greyed out and there is a lock next to the partition

That particular lock means the partition is mounted; it has nothing to do with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make permanent changes to always open an application as superuser, the root user, because, as others have stated, it defeats the inherent security of Linux.

Instead, *where needed*, open the application using *sudo*. It may seem like an extra step, but that is well worth the trouble to avoid having antimalware continuously running in the background, as is needed by another popular operating system.

For example, to run [gedit as super](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-edit-as-root.html.en), open Terminal and enter `sudo gedit`. Close that instance of gedit when done. "Editing files as the root user is potentially dangerous, and may break your system in bad ways."

The [Dolphin file manager has a built-in check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990611/how-to-run-dolphin-as-root) to prevent the unwary from causing harm. That said, I admit to this risky practice (and make disk images to prepare for a disaster I might create). [PCManFM](https://opensource.com/article/22/12/linux-file-manager-pcmanfm) is another file manager that [does *not* kvetch when launched sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287321/command-for-opening-pcmanfm-from-the-terminal-with-sudo-permission)... but it may break some functionality. *Caveat operator!*

As for being unable to make changes to a drive, if it is mounted, some operations are *verboten*. That would be like trying to change the distributor cap on a car while driving it. *First* unmount, *then* modify.

Comment: The other popular operating system has measures that _allow_ it to mix elevated apps and non-elevated ones (namely, integrity levels) as part of UAC; X11 has nothing like that. It's amazing we haven't had daily incidents of bad apps injecting "sudo..." keystrokes into Xterm, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[How to run programs as root user without using Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442542/how-to-run-programs-as-root-user-without-using-terminal/442564#442564)
has the following
[answer by Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/a/442564/963426)
that can help with your problem:

> If you want to run programs without using Terminal, I can deduce that
> you mean only GUI programs. And each one from all these GUI
> applications have in general an .desktop file located in
> `/usr/share/applications/` or in your user directory
> `~/.local/share/applications`. So to start a program as root you must
> to edit or better duplicate its associated .desktop file.
>
> Let's take for example **Gedit**, the default GUI editor in Ubuntu.
> Its .desktop file is `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` and has
> the following content:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=gedit
> GenericName=Text Editor
> Comment=Edit text files
> Exec=gedit %U
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> StartupNotify=true
> MimeType=text/plain;
> Icon=accessories-text-editor
> Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
> X-GNOME-DocPath=gedit/gedit.xml
> X-GNOME-FullName=Text Editor
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gedit
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.10.4
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-ExtraInfoScript=/usr/share/gedit/gedit-bugreport
> Actions=Window;Document;
> Keywords=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;
> X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit
>
> [Desktop Action Window]
> Name=Open a New Window
> Exec=gedit --new-window
> OnlyShowIn=Unity;
>
> [Desktop Action Document]
> Name=Open a New Document
> Exec=gedit --new-document
> OnlyShowIn=Unity;
> ```
>
> Now create a duplicate of this file as follow:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop /usr/share/applications/root_gedit.desktop
> ```
>
> and make the following changes:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]  
> Name=gedit as root  
> GenericName=Text Editor as root  
> Comment=Edit text files  
> Exec=gksudo gedit %U  
> Terminal=false  
> Type=Application  
> StartupNotify=true  
> MimeType=text/plain;
> Icon=accessories-text-editor  
> Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;  
> X-GNOME-DocPath=gedit/gedit.xml  
> X-GNOME-FullName=Text Editor  
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME  
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gedit  
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general  
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.10.4  
> X-GNOME-Bugzilla-ExtraInfoScript=/usr/share/gedit/gedit-bugreport  
> Actions=Window;Document;  
> Keywords=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;  
> X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit
>
> [Desktop Action Window]  
> Name=Open a New Window  
> Exec=gksudo gedit --new-window  
> OnlyShowIn=Unity;
>
> [Desktop Action Document]  
> Name=Open a New Document  
> Exec=gksudo gedit --new-document  
> OnlyShowIn=Unity;
> ```
>
> After this, when you will search for `gedit` in the Dash you will see
> two instances of gedit: one named **Text Editor** and one **Text
> Editor as root**. You should open that one named **Text Editor as
> root** if you want to run gedit as root.
>
> **Note:** `gksudo` must to be installed in order to use it. If you don't have installed, you can install it from terminal using:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gksudo
> ```

Comment: `gksudo` doesn't appear to be a package in Debian anymore https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gksudo&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all `pkexec` is apparently popular now. Or `sudo -A [program]` if /etc/sudo.conf has a line like "`Path askpass /usr/bin/ssh-askpass`"